# Top align [leading, title, trailing] widgets of the ListTile

Tags: flutter

I have a list of `ListTile` and I want the leading, title and trailing to be top aligned.

If all of them will be a text widget, `titleAlignment: ListTileTitleAlignment.top` is working fine. But for me the title is a TextButton which have some internal padding which I have have removed using `Offset`.

But now problem is, If I have one line text, everything is fine but when I increase the number of line in the button. Alignment got removed.

[image]

Here is the source code: https://pastebin.com/LRATu9kB

Also the while using Divider the gap is not equal from top and bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `titleAlignment: ListTileTitleAlignment.top` doesn't align them properly is because `TextButton` widget has a default padding that is higher than the `Icon` and `Text` default padding vertically.

Instead of using `Transform.translate` widget for an `offset` parameter, you can make all widgets have a matching padding (vertical in this case) by setting a `minVerticalPadding: 10.0` parameter in `ListTile` widget. Increase the padding until they're equal.

See demo [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=192aa1bf22c0683e8ea7d1fd5f309c15)

As an added bonus, [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e943b4863ac0e9ffcc190224950dc648) is another method for customisation purposes. Using Text with InkWell instead of TextButton